# How to extract specific pages based on a formula?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pdf, tabula

I'm trying to extract pages from a PDF that is 1000 pages long but I only need pages in the pattern of [9,10,17,18,25,26,33,34,...etc]. These numbers can be represented in the formula: `pg = 1/2 (7 - 3 (-1)^n + 8*n)`.

I tried to define the formula and plug into `tabula.read_pdf` but I'm not sure how to define the 'n' variable where 'n' ranges from 0 up to 25. Right now I defined it as a list which I think is the problem...

```
n = list(range(25+1))
pg = 1/2 (7 - 3 (-1)^n + 8*n) 

df = tabula.read_pdf(path, pages = 'pg',index_col=0, multiple_tables=False)
```

When trying to execute, I get a TypeError: 'int' object is not callable on line `pg = 1/2 (7 - 3 (-1)^n + 8*n)`. How would I define the variables so that tabula extracts pages that fit the condition of the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula is **x = 1/2(8n - 3(-1)^n + 7)**

Step1:

```
pg = []  #Empty list to store the pages numbers calculated by formula
for i in range(1, 25+1):     # For 1000 pages pdf use 1000 instead of 25
    k = int(1/2*((8*n[i])-3*((-1)**n[i])+7))
    pg.append(k)

print(pg, end = '')  # This will give you list of page numbers

#[9, 10, 17, 18, 25, 26, 33, 34, 41, 42, 49, 50, 57, 58, 65, 66, 73, 74, 81, 82, 89, 90, 97, 98, 105]
```

Step 2:

```
# Now run the loop through each of the pages with the table

df=pd.DataFrame([])
df_combine=pd.DataFrame([])

for pageiter in range(pg):
            df = tabula.read_pdf(path, pages=pageiter+1 ,index_col=0, multiple_tables=False, guess=False) #modify it as per your requirement
            df_combine=pd.concat([df,df_combine]) #you can choose between merge or concat as per your need
```

OR

```
df_data = []
for pageiter in range(pg):
            df = tabula.read_pdf(path, pages=pageiter+1 ,index_col=0, multiple_tables=False, guess=False) #modify it as per your requirement
            df_data.append(df)

df_combine= pd.concat(df_data, axis=1)
```

Reference link to create formula
https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=a3af2e675c3bfae0f2ecce820c2bef43

Comment: Really appreciate the help. In regards to 'Step 1', when I print the list of page numbers, I get vastly different values than it should be. Expected pages are [9, 10, 17, 18, 25, 26, 33, 34, 41, 42, 49, 50...] but output shows [5.0, 1.5, 12.0, 8.5, 23.0, 19.5, 30.0, 26.5...]. I double checked the formula and it's correct. Is there something that I'm missing??